# 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0110' in position 1: character maps to <undefined> while reading csv file using pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding

So I have searched a lot in google why I am getting this error, but wherever I go, the solution is to use a different encoding like cp1252, iso-8859-1, latin1 or utf-8. I am actually using utf-8 an tried all other encodings too while using pd.read_csv.

When I read the csv in a different PC with the same encoding, it does not throw this error. So I think this is a fault with my local machine.

This is how i read my csv :

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_path + file_name, dtype='object', encoding="UTF-8")
```

If there is any other characters like arabic or chinese, i get this error saying

```
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0110' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>
```

while reading csv file using pd.read_csv

I have visited a lot of stack overflow and a lot of other solution providers but none of them fix my problem. This is the fault with my local machine. So can anyone help me figure out where this problem persists ?

Thank you

Comment: You need to specify the encoding *that was used to save the file*. You have to know what this is, one way or another. The easiest way is if you're using files that were written by the same program; then you pick an encoding sufficient for your needs (when in doubt, UTF-8) and use it for both reading and writing. If you don't know the encoding, then we can't possibly help you unless we have the binary contents of the file.

Comment: However, notice that the error message references the `charmap` codec even though that is not the encoding you used to open the file. This cannot happen simply from the `read_csv` call; it is something that can happen *when you try to display* the Dataframe, and it happens because *the environment is not properly configured to show those characters*. For that problem, you should try https://superuser.com.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have used the same encoding UTF-8 for writing as well and I am using UTF-8 for reading as well. So I will check superuser.com. I am sure its the problem with my local machine environment.

Comment: `'\u0110'`  (== `Đ` _Latin Capital Letter D With Stroke_) is defined eg in `cp1250` (Central Europe) or `cp1258` (Vietnamese)